# Capture signature from wpf

Tags: wpf

I would like to capture a signature from (file, pad) in a WPF application.  How can I implement this?  Is there any API available?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to capture an image you can obviously just use a canvas or something like that.  If you need to actually verify the signature, I've used KeCrypt before which is quite cool.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, but if your looking for a way to allow the user to sign your application and you capture that signature then you should look at the InkCanvas. There is a decent article here to get you started: http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0704102&page=2